# QML Row: How to extend qml containers (Row or Column) from other file

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

It seems should have a solution for sure.
Suppose I have a Test.qml file containing this:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    color: "green"

    Row {
        id: row
        spacing: 10
        anchors.fill: parent
        Rectangle {
            color: "red";
            width: 100;
            height: 100;
        }
        Rectangle {
            color: "red";
            width: 100;
            height: 100;
        }
        Rectangle {
            color: "red";
            width: 100;
            height: 100;
        }
    }
}
```

Now suppose we want to use this Test.qml within another file like main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")


    Test {
        anchors.fill: parent;
        // I want to be able to add new items (rects) to the row inside Test.qml
    }
}
```

Now suppose we want to extend items to the row object in Test.qml, But we want to add from main.qml. How we can do that? is that even possible?

(FYI: The application of this feature would be to develop a placeholder form and fill the items in the other items so we can skip duplicate codes. )

Comment: Use QML Loader for this

Comment: @Ponzifex Can you post an example? I think for QML Loader it's needed to use Components as the source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without creating objects dynamically. You need to use a [default property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#default-properties) that is aliased to the contents of your Row. A default property means Items that get added to your object will actually be assigned to that property instead. In Test.qml, add this:

```
Rectangle {
    color: "green"
    default property alias contents: row.data

    Row {
        id: row
        ...
     }
}
```

Now you can add other items to it from main.qml, like this:

```
    Test {
        anchors.fill: parent;
        
        // Automatically gets added to 'row'
        Rectangle {
            color: "blue"
            width: 100
            height: 100
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [create objects dynamically](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html#creating-objects-dynamically):

```
MyRow.qml:
Row {
    id: row
    spacing: 10
    anchors.fill: parent
    Rectangle {
        color: "red";
        width: 100;
        height: 100;
    }
}
      
main.qml:
MyRow{
    id: myRow
    Component.onCompleted: Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 2.0; Rectangle {color: "green"; width: 100; height: 100}', myRow)
}
```

Comment: I believe there should be a better solution.